# Are there *3* interpretations of probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian

In probability, we learn that there has two interpretations :

- frequentist
  $P=\lim_{nb\ experiments\rightarrow\infty} \frac{favorable\ cases}{nb\ experiments}$
- bayesian
  $P=$ degree of belief of the probability

Now, there is the formula that we learn at school : $P=\frac{favorable\ cases}{nb\ cases}$

is it an "interpretation" ? Is it a *third* one ?
Is it the "classical interpretation of probability", as wikipedia tends to state ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations

Does it has a relationship with the two others ?

Why are there only *two* interpretations in this other wikipedia :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Interpretations

(remark, some authors call "classic" interpretation the frequentist one)

Comment: There are other interpretations of probability, see e.g. [Standford Encylopedia entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/) which is just an overview of main interpretations.

Comment: Its important to note that what academia accepts as a list of "interpretations of probability" is not necessarily exhaustive or even particularly meaningful (except in a historical sense).  In practice, probabilities are model-relative and are not interpretable without the context of the procedure that produced them, and so philosophical beliefs about what probability "means" are largely moot.

It may be of more interest to instead study different axiomatizations of probability directly, without the interpretive bent.

Comment: i think that 1 begets 3 in fair circumstances. think of flipping a coin.

Comment: Your third formula seems more in line with picking a single ball out of a bin with $n$ total balls, $k$ of which are red. It holds for models where "all outcomes are equally likely."  I do think that is a much better place to start than the other two (which are interpretations that I cannot really interpret).